# Will PMP help a technical employee move to a management level position?

Tags: career-development, project-management, career-switch, certification

I've been technical for almost 3 years in the software industry, a lecturer for 3 years in a software engineering department, and an adviser for 2 years.

Will a certificate like PMP helps me move to a management position like a software project manager?

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate? Right now your question reads like bullet points. Also did you check the other questions on this site related to the PMP certification? Mention or make note in your question of what else has been discussed and what more you want to know as it can help someone give opinions or experience on this topic.

Comment: Voting to close the question as the answers will be opinion based. Speaking English helps in general, but it is unlikely to be a specific deciding factor. Dittto with any kind of education or work experience taken by itself. The determination as to whether they help in any individual case is purely subjective and dependent on what the individual chooses to believe Needless to say, if it's subjective, it's opinion based.

Comment: And tell us what a PMP is, and since it's probably country/region specific add your country as a tag. are you training to be a Portable Multimedia Player
or a Precision Machined Product?

Comment: FYI, PMP is Project Management Professional, which is a common certification in the software industry: http://www.pmi.org/Certification/Project-Management-Professional-PMP.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to second [Jared's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/33466/9264), and add to it.

A few years ago I worked as a contractor on a project being run by a person who had a PMP certificate.  He also was a graduate of the U.S. Air Force Academy (arguably one of the most intellectually challenging institutions in the world) with a degree in Human Factor Analysis.

He told me he had actually failed the PMP exam the first time he took it, relying on his education background.  He looked at his results, realized it was a "memorization test," memorized the content, passed it, and declared it BS.  The only reason he re-took it is that the consultancy was "hot" for people with PMP's as project leads, back then.

The whole program operates from (IMO) a faulty premise.  It requires more project history for people with Associate's degrees than it does for people with Bachelor's degrees.  I'm not saying that getting a degree is a worthless achievement, but it is by no means any measure of ability, especially leadership ability.  I know hyperbolic examples aren't any more valid, but I've known high school dropouts who can crew and run an entire oil rig and people with Master's and PhD degrees who couldn't lead ducks to a lake.

If you want to move to a management role, work on the following:

- **Budgeting / Budget Management.**  No one likes doing it, but it needs done.  Get good at it.  In the end, every project boils down to deliverable quality vs. time and resources spent.  The best managers optimize that equation.  You can't optimize it if you don't understand one of the three components.
- **Critical listening skills.**  A lot of people like to complain, but behind the complaint is a "pain point."  Even the most inconsolable employee/customer has some truth behind their whining.  Learn to pick up on what's really happening, leaving the emotion out of it.  Listen for phrases like, "When I ... " or "I can't even ..."  What comes out next is your most important issue.
- **Communication.**  I had a guy working for me this summer who was terrible at communication.  He did good work (not great, but good), but you never knew if it was done or not because he wouldn't tell anyone what he did.  I had to resort to requiring "End of Shift" reports from him detailing his day's activities.  (In fairness, he was young, and this was his first job out of school.)  If you want to be seen as a leader, communicate what you've accomplished.  Don't brag, just communicate.  If you get a team, even as a member and not a leader, communicate to the leader/manager, giving the team credit, and don't take any for yourself.  *ANYONE* can pull off a technical feat, given time and resources.  The quality of a leader is knowing why and when it needed done in the first place, and putting the best resources on the task.  Communicate what you/your team did and why you did it.
- **Taking responsibility.**  Sometimes that means shouldering the load.  Sometimes it means taking the heat.  No manager wants to play detective.  They want to bring the assignment to someone and know it will get done.  They want to know what happened if something went wrong.  They really don't care who to blame (well, if they're a good manager, anyway).  Be that person who takes things off their desk.  Be the person who "takes the heat" for the team.  It is no feat of leadership to stand up and take the credit for other people's work.  It is a significant mark of a leader to stand up and take the blame for something they weren't solely responsible for.  Do that once or twice and you'll have the respect of your team.  And that brings me to:
- **Understanding what leadership really is.**  Leadership is not about giving directions.  Leadership is about convincing those around you that following you is the best course of action for them personally.  The best way to convince someone is to demonstrate it.  Don't hand out 15 tasks and then leave early.  Don't accept any public praise without crediting your teammates for their contributions.  Don't see yourself as "above" your team.  Without a team, a "leader" is nothing.  Always remember that.

BTW - they say a picture is worth a thousand words?  Well, they're right.  This sums up my entire post and then some:

[image: Leadership]

Comment: Have you ever tried to lead ducks anywhere?  It's hard!

Comment: It's easy if you're trying to lead them to where they're already going.

Comment: There's a word for that, it's called "birdwatching"... lol

Comment: That's the implied basis of my sarcasm.  Maybe it's not coming through in text, well.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, **No**.  PMP is on it's way out in many circles to the point where it may actually disqualify you for some positions.  A heavyweight certification process that doesn't actually give you the skills necessary for management just doesn't provide much value.  And maintaining it with all of the CEU's is a pain too.  From my understanding, most of the courses (not all) are focused on older techniques that are less applicable to modern software development.

You'd be better off getting a scrummaster or product owner certification if you are open to using Agile methodologies (which are much more in-demand than PMPs).  You'll also need work experience to complement any certification, but it's a much easier to transition to a scrummaster or PO role from a developer role than to jump straight to a management role.

To be clear **the best way to get a management position is to demonstrate on-the-job leadership progressing toward a management position**.  Certifications are not a magic replacement for this.

FYI, I'm a software development manager who rejected investing in a PMP, and only recently got a scrummaster certification.  Neither of these was needed to become a manager.

Comment: I really thank you for taking the time to answer me in this details. ScrumMaster is Actually in the list of Certificates and i do have experience in scrum please have a look at this question.    http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/33439/will-certifications-and-or-mba-masters-guarantee-you-management-job-moving-from

Comment: @jared: Your comment may fit your specific niche. However, in my experience, I have seen a lot of PMP certified managers happily employed in IT. This is because the PMP certifies good management (of paper, not people) process knowledge that would otherwise have to be taught. As a manager, I'd rather have someone I can hire with a strong base of knowledge to improve on, than none (or an unknown about of knowledge).

Comment: @MikeVanTrufflebutt: I would definitely not argue that there are happily employed PMP's out there, but from the perspective of someone "breaking in" to software management, it is often not the best option these days as companies realize that setting up process for process sake is not advantageous.  I'm not trying to start an "agile holy war" on the merits of this, but few can deny that jobs for agile managers are increasing more rapidly than for PMP's and other traditional managers (which increases competition for the fewer jobs, making "breaking in" harder).

Comment: @jared PMP's don't care whether you decide to do agile or waterfall, or whatever. For them its about the project, of which development is just one part. That's really the difference. Whether the OP wants to break into business (PM) or technical (agile vs waterfall), is up to him. My point was to provide an alternate point of view. If his goal is to be a business manager, then a PMP will definately help. If he wants to be a software development manager, an agile certification will help. I have both. Its nice. :-P

Comment: I didn't know PMP was focused on software development. How could this certification "disqualify" someone

Comment: @Brandlin So, to be clear, it is rare that a PMP would disqualify someone, but some companies feel like they want to only use agile techniques and that PMP is a big investment and buy-in to waterfall techniques.  I know some have argued that a project manager isn't affected by agile, and the agile zealots would say that that person doesn't really understand agile because it affects **everyone's** jobs.  To be fair, I live in Austin which has one of the more agile leaning development communities in the US (AFAIK), and this thinking isn't really common, but it is out there.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, obtaining the PMP will help you break into pure (business) management roles like project management. In fact, that is exactly how I broke into higher-levels of management many years ago.  Just note, the PMP is not an entry-level certification. You must have a pretty substantial amount of management experience in order to even qualify for the test. And then, the test is no piece of cake to take.

Before we go further, lets talk about what a business manager does versus what a technical manager does. Both tracks have entry-level positions. A business manager is more concerned with budgets, big-picture, long-term strategic impacts. A projects manager is a business manager, but they are focused on the scope of thier project. A technical manager is a technical specialty like software development manager. Think of it as half technical lead, and half project manager. They are focused on schedules, and usually not costs. They are focused on tasking and technical deliverables, not what the earned value of each deliverable is.  A PMP is a great certification for anyone who wants to eventually get into a pure business management role.

A lot of has been said in this answer list about the soft-skills (communication, listening, leadership) you'll need to be a good manager, but not enough has been said about the hard-skills (accounting, paperwork, scheduling) you will also need. The old adage is that leaders lead people and managers manage paperwork. Well, the PMP is for managers, and if you start studying the PMP, you'll learn all about management processes you'll need to know about to be a good project manager.

As far as soft-skills go, you'll start with some and learn more. Some of the learning will be painful, some will not. Some of the lessons will get you fired, others will get you promoted. The only soft-skills you will need in abundance from the start of your journey into management is the humility to accept critiques, the intelligence to use them, and the wisdom to listen more than you speak.

Comment: "You must have a pretty substantial amount of management experience in order to even qualify for the test" This requirement is usually instituted as a CYA to prevent gifted 14-year kids from India from taking the test and passing it- This happened wrt CISSP (an IT security certification),and they instituted that requirement in a hurried fashion because yes, a 14-year old kid from India passed the test, thereby proving that CISSP is just a paper certification.

Comment: As far as I know the requirement has been around since the credential first came into being. Not reactionary, but foundational.